# rails 3.2 and datatable example

Tags: jquery, datatables

Trying to do a simple datatables implementation with my rails 3.2 app.  I have this exact app working in PHP and wanted to port it to ruby.  I am not a Ruby expert just learning it.

I am basically following this example but with my Code and DB

http://asciicasts.com/episodes/340-datatables

- I created my table and gave it a class and ID
- I added this file -> /app/assets/javascripts/products.js.coffee   which contains

  jQuery ->
    $('#run-table').dataTable

  ```
    sPaginationType: "full_numbers"
    bServerSide: true
    iDisplayLength: 4
    aaSorting:[]
  ```

What I see on my web page is a properly formatted table with columns, sort icons, search filter text box, pagination numbers all correct. But it does not work.

If I do "bServerSide: true"  Then any time I interact with the table I get

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found  - http://localhost:3000/null?sEcho=1&iColumns=11&sColumns=&iDisplayStart=0&iDisplayLength=4&...
```

So if I sort or add a search filter I get that error.

If I change it to "bServerSide: false"  Then I get a correct looking table that load with my initial data but does nothing.  No sorting, no filter, no pagination.

The part from that sample code I did not do was -> /app/datatables/products_datatable.rb   because I did not see a need for it.  With PHP I dont use server side and its about 4 lines of code to get this working.

Any help would be great I can provide more code snippets if needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was a bug in my code in the view.  I had tbody  defined inside my loop I needed to move it above my loop.  Stupid bug that I spent hours staring at and did not see it.

This works fine now

```
     <tbody>


<% @run.each do |c| %>

    <tr>

    <td><%= link_to c.idRun, step_url(c.idRun) -%>  </td>

    <td> <%= c.run_name %></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using  "bServerSide" = true then you should provide "sAjaxSource" for your own implementation of serverside processing, like retrieving data from db, make queries for sorting, filtering, paging.

Else all you have to do is define your table with the same id as in jquery datatable initialization and that's all to get it work with filtering, sorting, paging out of box.

Such initialization should be enough without server side :

```
 jQuery ->
 $('#tableid').dataTable
```

Comment: When I do that which is how I  thought it should work.  I get a fully defined table with all my data from the initial load defined in my controller BUT it does nothing.  No sort, no filter, no pagination. No errors anyplace.  Maybe I need something in my controller?  or maybe its the rails datatables gem? gem 'jquery-datatables-rails'

Comment: sorry I should also that by saying it does nothing I mean I have a great looking data table with all the fixings.  page numbers, a filter text box, column sort icons.  the table loads with full data but none of the datatables features do anything.  no errors no anything.  The sort icon will change but no sort.  Filter text can be added but no filter, if I set display length iDisplayLength: 4   it ignores it.